# C++ get every number separately

Tags: c++, integer, division

I have a range of numbers from 100 to 999. I need to get every number separately of it and check whether it can be divided by 2. For example:

```
232
2 divided by 2 = 1 = true
3 divided by 2 = 1.5 = false
2 divided by 2 = 1 = true
```

and so on.

To get the first number all I have to do is to divide the entire number by 100.

```
int x = 256;
int k = x/100;
```

so `x` would hold a value of 2.

Now, is there a way to check those other ones? Because `k = x/10;` would already be 25.

Comment: Hint: get rid of the 2 before dividing by 10 :)

Comment: You can use the `%` (modulus) operator to get decide divisibility.

Comment: @pboy Yet people still provide full code answers. Oh well, what can you do...

Comment: Or convert the number to string and get it one char at-at-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int x = 256;
int i = x / 100; // i is 2
int j = (x % 100) / 10; // j is 5
int k = (x % 10); // k is 6
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe look into integer division and the modulo.

```
int k1 = (x / 10) % 10 // "10s"
int k2 = ( x / 100 ) % 10 // "100s"
//etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo to get the last digit of the number, then divide by ten to discard the last digit.

Repeat while the number is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the modulus operator `%`. It does a division and returns the reminder.

```
1 % 2 = 1
2 % 2 = 0
3 % 2 = 1
4 % 2 = 0
...
```

Answer (score -2):

eg. take 232:

```
int num = 232;
int at_ones_place = num % 10;
int at_tens_place = ( num /10 ) % 10 ;
int at_hundreds_place = (num /100);
```

Comment: Oh my god, what is this abomination?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be feels like a textbook question "spot the mistakes"

Comment: @Let_Me_Be what do you mean?

Comment: @Aditya I'm sorry, but there are so many errors in the code, both syntactic and semantic that there simply isn't enough space in the comment to describe them all. For starters, try to compile and run the code.